# How to reset a do while loop? I keep getting a "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException" error

Tags: java, do-while

I am trying to make a program which displays a list to convert from Infix to Postfix and vice versa. However, when the loop restarts, it keeps asking me whether I want to continue and as soon as I hit "y", it throws an Illegal Argument Exception.

I would really appreciate the help.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ConversionTest1
{
  public enum Choices
  {one, two, three, four, y; }
  public static void main(String [ ] args)
  {
    try
    {
      LinkedStackClass lstack = new LinkedStackClass();
      InfixToPostfix obj = new InfixToPostfix();
      PostFixtoInFix object = new PostFixtoInFix();
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      char ch;
      int[] opt = {1,2,3,4};
      int size;
      do
      {
        System.out.println("Please select what type of conversion you would like to do: ");
        System.out.println(" 1) Infix to postfix ");
        System.out.println(" 2) Postfix to infix ");
        System.out.println(" 3) Print Equations ");
        System.out.println(" 4) Exit ");
        String choice = scan.nextLine();
          switch (Choices.valueOf(choice))
          {
            case one : 
              System.out.println("Infix : \t");
            //  lstack.obj(console.nextInt());
              String infix = scan.nextLine();
              System.out.println("Postfix : \t"+obj.convert(infix));
            //  System.out.println("Postfix : \t"+obj.convert(obj));
              //lstack.insertAtStart( scan.nextInt() );                     
              break; 

            case two : 
              System.out.println(" 2) postfix to infix ");
              System.out.println("Postfix : ");
            String postfix = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Infix : "+object.convert(postfix));
              //list.insertAtStart( scan.nextInt() );                     
              break; 

            case three : 
              System.out.println(" 3) Print Equations ");
              System.out.println("Print Equations!");
             // list.insertAtStart( scan.nextInt() );                     
              break; 

            case four : 
              System.out.println(" 4) Exit ");
              //list.insertAtStart( scan.nextInt() );   
              System.exit(0);
              break; 
        //    case y:
          //    System.out.println("Working!");
            //  break;
              default : 
              System.out.println("Wrong Entry \n ");
              break; 
          }

        System.out.println("\nDo you want to continue (Type y or n) \n");
        ch = scan.next().charAt(0); 
      } while(ch == 'Y'|| ch == 'y');
    }
    catch(EmptyStackException e)
    {
      System.out.println("I caught it!");
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: It's possible that there is still a newline character in your `Scanner`'s buffer and you should use `Scanner#nextLine`

Comment: MadProgrammer's answer is correct, I tested the logic and scan.nextLine() solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

you should use scan.nextLine(); just for clean your buffer because is taken a blank space " " and this value doesn't exist in your enum.

try this at the end after read the character, this should clean up your buffer!
good luck.

```
     case four : 
              System.out.println(" 4) Exit ");
              //list.insertAtStart( scan.nextInt() );   
              System.exit(0);
              break; 
        //    case y:
          //    System.out.println("Working!");
            //  break;
              default : 
              System.out.println("Wrong Entry \n ");
              break; 
          }

        System.out.println("\nDo you want to continue (Type y or n) \n");
        ch = scan.next().charAt(0); 
        scan.nextLine();
      } while(ch == 'Y'|| ch == 'y');
    }
    catch(EmptyStackException e)
    {
      System.out.println("I caught it!");
    }
```